# Apache Hudi Upsert/Insert/Deletes at the same time

Tags: apache-hudi

Can we run write operation type **Upsert** and **Delete** at the same time and same table?

Is Apache Hudi meta get corrupted??

Please help here to do the same using other if any solutions.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Hudi, you can upsert and delete records in the same query, without corrupting the Hudi metadata, to achieve this you have two options:

- develop your own `hoodie.datasource.write.payload.class` and implement the logic in the class, where you can delete the records based on some condition (for ex when you provide a null value or based on a column value)
- add the column `_hoodie_is_deleted` to your dataset source, and provide `true` for the records you want to delete, and keep it `null` for the records you want to upsert (mode `Append` and operation `upsert`)

## Update:

If you want to run them in two separate queries, they are considered as 2 [concurrent writes](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/concurrency_control/#supported-concurrency-controls), you can activate OCC (optimistic concurrency control) which allow concurrent writes when there is no overlap (DELETE from partition X, and INSERT in partition Y), but when both queries are writing to the same partitions, they will both fail.

Comment: I wanted to run both things in parallel, 1st job can do UPSERT/INSERT and 2nd can do DELETE, also I don't want to capture deleted records in any column for now.

Comment: @PRAVINMASKE The question was not clear to me, I thought you want to do both in the same query, I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add hudi config: 'hoodie.write.concurrency.mode': 'optimistic_concurrency_control'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).